# Virtually everything is significant if the sample sizes are large enough

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, p-value

Forgive me, I'm sure this is a very simple statistics question.

I frequently run into the problem where I try to determine the effect of a single variable, so I split my data into sets that are positive or negative for that variable. Unfortunately, I fall into a reverse-p-hacking problem. Whereas people p-hack to find features that are statistically significant, I find that if my sample size is large enough, virtually every feature is significant.

To make this an answerable question, how would you approach determining the significance of a given feature between two (very large) groups controlling for the fact that the significance will be inflated by group size?

Comment: The question in your hypothesis test is if a parameter equals some value. If the parameter is really close to that value, then it is not equal to that value, so the p-value is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. It is alerting you that there is a small but detectable deviation from the hypothesized value. $\text{//}$ How to proceed will depend on what you're doing, and that is not clear to me. Please elaborate on your task.